# How to get alert when crontab changes?

Tags: cron

I've got about a dozen servers that each have crontabs with anywhere from 20-50 crontab entries.   My single most common cause of a process failure is someone commenting out jobs in cron during a fix or patch and then forgetting to uncomment the jobs.

I'd like to do two things to solve this:

1. Start using our schedule suppression process that allows users to suppress schedules without actually touching crontab.  Nothing magical - just touch a file in a directory dedicated to the process.  The process checks that directory on start-up.
2. Implement a process that will send out alerts if crontab doesn't match its backup or current version in svn.

Can anyone recommend an existing solution for #2 (alert when crontab changes)?

Answer (score 0):

In this case i would suggest to compare hashvalues of the file you want to have and the actual file.

Just write a little bashscript that sends out a emailnotification or creates a notification file or whatever you want and let this script be run automatically every x seconds / minutes / hours.

A possible script could be

```
if [[ $(md5sum path/to/crontab.backup | cut -d' ' -f1) == $(md5sum /etc/crontab | cut -d' ' -f1) ]]
then
    # send your notification
fi
```

This is a very simple solution to check if a file was changed since the last backup was made.

Comment: Thanks, I had considered this implementation.  I'm assuming it should run a diff, not md5sum; run from root to avoid losing its check if crontab is deleted; and should be able to pull from svn/cvs/git/etc.  But I'd prefer a really solid tool just in case I'm overlooking any other helpful functionality here.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the inotify system that is available since kernel 2.6.13. See http://www.infoq.com/articles/inotify-linux-file-system-event-monitoring

Comment: I hadn't considered inotify - that's an interesting idea.  But in this case I don't have performance or accuracy concerns - a diff of a crontab won't be a challenge.   I think diffing against an entry in svn is probably my best bet.