# how to have "crontab -e" emit an "installing new crontab" email

Tags: linux, cron

When I update a crontab, a message is emitted on the screen:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
```

How does one configure it to also send out an email to a designated address?

```
$ uname -a
Linux dev 3.12.62-60.64.8-default #1 SMP Tue Oct 18 12:21:38 UTC 2016 (42e0a66) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: can you please explain why the downtick and close?

Answer (score 1):

At least [Vixie Cron](https://linux.die.net/man/8/cron) does not have that function. But you could set up a syslog listener as crontab changes are logged there. I suspect some system monitoring security packages would be able to do that (but cant recall anyone from the top of my head, other answers cant either: [How to get alert when crontab changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692977/how-to-get-alert-when-crontab-changes)).

Comment: I use `aide` for monitoring file changes, but would prefer an immediate alert